# How to determine the unit cell in heterostructure?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, vesta, supercell, heterostructures

I’ve to create a heterostructure from two monolayers, for example, two graphene sheets or two metal layers. And then I want to rotate the first layer relative to another one by some angle. The question is how to define a new unit cell in order to calculate it periodically. Are there any algorithms or software to help with that?

Comment: Bump! I have run into a similar problem trying to model a shearing defect in a crystal, i.e. how to find the unitcell. Hopefully we can get an answer!

Comment: @TylerSterling. I think this https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.3c00932 has the answer for what you might be looking for, the shell script they have used is freely avaialble on https://zenodo.org/records/8304785.

Comment: @Victor, if this https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.3c00932 will answer your question, I might write an answer when I have time.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez awesome!! Thanks!